# Laravel eloquent build child object from parent with mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am using laravel 5.1 and jenssegers mongodb and I am having some issues with such structure

```
    class ServiceProvider extends Eloquent {
        protected $collection = 'service_provider';
        protected $connection = 'mongodb';

        public static function factory($serviceId) {
           switch ($serviceId) {
            case self::SERVICE_PROVIDER_CHILD_CARE : {
                return new ChildCareServiceProvider();
            }
            break;
           }
        }
        public static get_by_service_id($service_id) {
          return self::find($serviceId)->first();
        }
    }
    class ChildCareServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements IServiceProvider
    {
        protected $collection = 'service_provider';
        protected $connection = 'mongodb';

        public function availabilityTimes()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ServiceProvider\ServiceProviderAvailabilityTime');
        }
    }
```

When I am saving or updating service provider I know what kind of service it is , so I can use factory method to get child and save it. But when I am getting service by id - I dont know service type yet, I only know its id. So I do have a method in ServiceProvider which makes query to mongo collection and getting record by its id. In this case that record will be an instance of object ServiceProvider. Is there an easy way to create ChildCareServiceProvider object from ServiceProvider object data? I tried something like

```
$data = ServiceProvider::find($serviceId)->first()->attributesToArray();
$serviceProvider = new ChildCareServiceProvider($data);
```

but in this case $serviceProvider object internal structure is little bit different in terms of its internal properties, which somehow affects my availabilityTimes relationship

I am sorta new to laravel and mongo, any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PHP's magic methods. What you can do is set the entity and then for example the __get() and __set() methods, set/get the value from/to the entity.